# What type of sorting is this?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, perl, mapping

I have written a simple sorting algorithm and would like to know what type is it?
It just maps the initial array's elements into an empty array with the indexes of the values of the initial elements.

```
my @arg = (5, 14, 12, 9, 1, 17, 3, 19, 20, 4, 6, 15, 8, 18, 7, 2, 10, 13, 11, 16);
my @out;
map { $out[$_] = $_ } @arg;
print join " ", @out;
```

Sure there can be added shrinking to the output array as in the real world there can be *holes* in indexes.
Also, this example can be extended for working with doubles. For this sake, I would suggest using other data structures (i.e.: trees or linked lists)

### UPDATE

Benchmarks:

```
                   Rate uniqsort   bubble  mapping perlsort
    uniqsort  82274/s       --     -29%     -87%     -90%
    bubble   115925/s      41%       --     -81%     -86%
    mapping  614399/s     647%     430%       --     -25%
    perlsort 814352/s     890%     602%      33%       --
```

- &uniqsort - using `List::MoreUtils` via `uniq sort @arr`;
- &bubble - the basic bubble sort
- &mapping - this one
- &perlsort - using `sort {$a<=>$b} @arr`

Comment: This is kind of like counting sort, which counts the number of occurrences of every integer, then just list those integers.

Comment: seems to be a [pgeonhole sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort), except you seem to assume no duplication in `@arg`

Comment: It does not look like sorting, you utilize array's feature by placing an element into an array using number as index. An array ordered structure based on index, in your case you generate an array with _holes_ in place of missing numbers, and as side effect of this approach deduplication will take place.

Comment: @PolarBear - as the number is an index in the new array duplications are impossible. Regarding holes - I mentioned shrinking as a further possible step to remove holes (any, even using grep). About the sorting itself - what is a sorting? A sorting is when some input row is get sorted on output. This rule is done by this simple mapping (with many limitations (doubles are missing, for example)).

Comment: @Arsenii -- if you remove `undef` elements then you will get ordered list. In case of numbers you could just use `sort` to achieve same result. What is the point of your code then? Why do you use `map` instead of `for`? In this particular case `for` fits much better -- `map` is intended to be used to store result in a data structure. `print join(' ', uniq sort @args);`

Comment: @PolarBear maybe just because sort is about 3 times slower than this one? :) Of course, sort works with doubles (if use {$a <=> $b}). I will try soon to extend for working with linked lists structure and then it will be working with doubles easily. I will benchmark it then and post here.

Comment: @Arsenii -- benchmark would be beneficial, it will demonstrate how your approach stacks up against `sort` and `uniq` (it is doubtful that your approach will outperform).

Comment: @PolarBear - I have just updated the post with a benchmark for you.

Comment: @Arsenii *"I have just updated the post with a benchmark for you"* Please include or provide a link to the code you used to produce the benchmark so we can try reproduce

Comment: Side note: using `map` in a void context is generally best avoided in favor of a for loop (Mentioned in `perlstyle` among others). `$out[$_] = $_ for @arg;` or `for (@arg) { $out[$_] = $_; }`

Comment: @Arsenii -- `perlsort` is faster than mapping by __32.5%__.

Comment: What is your question? If it's "what type of sort is this?", then the first 2 comments seem to answer it, and I don't understand why you added the benchmark and the paragraph starting with "Sure there can be added...". If not, then I don't know what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that doesn't sort the values because it produces the following:

```perl
undef, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

Note the extra element. It's a partially broken (no filtering of empty elements), partially specialized (no duplicates allowed) version of  [pigeonhole sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort).

---

By the way,

```perl
@out[@arg] = @arg;
```

should be faster than

```perl
map { $out[$_] = $_ } @arg;
```

Comment: Thank you, @ikegami. The nice point about @out[@arg] = @arg; I did not see the undef element in my output, because I did not dump it, using the classic module. I had to. Yes. :)

Comment: Warnings would have told you. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. Also, there would have been a leading space.